# How can I know email is duplicated with devise dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, devise

I made `sign_up page` with devise. In this page, inputed email can be checked valid or not. And it output the message dynamically with jQuery like this.

```js
// Output_email-message dynamically
$('#user_email').focusin(function () {
    $('#user_email').keyup(function () {
        $('#output-email').text('');
    })
});
$('#user_email').focusout(function () {
    $('#output-email').removeClass('field-output-comple').addClass('field-output');
    if ($('#user_email').val().length < 1) {
        $('#output-email').text('<%= t 'devise.registrations.output_email_blank' %>');
    } else if (!isValidEmailAddress($('#user_email').val())) {
        $('#output-email').text('<%= t 'devise.registrations.output_email_uncomple' %>');
    } else {
        $('#output-email').text('<%= t 'devise.registrations.output_email_comple' %>');
        $('#output-email').removeClass('field-output').addClass('field-output-comple');
    }
})
```

But I don't know how can I check this inputed email is duplicated or not dynamically. Is there any function can be useful in devise? Thanks for reading.

Comment: by duplicated you mean saved in database (server side) ? If so, juste make an ajax call to check it in your else.

Comment: you can use localstorage to save and check for it whenevr required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function in for example your users controller that takes one argument(email) and returns a boolean. This function could then be accessed through ajax using JQuery and then displayed.

```
def check_email
  return User.find_by(:email => params[:email]) ? true : false
end
```

And in your routes add

```
get '/users/:email' => 'users#check_email', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Then in your validate email function send an ajax request to check the email.

```
$.get('/users/'+$('#user_email').text(), function(data){
  // Print to html
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how code with ajax, so I did it with gem `gon`. After that I retry with ajax with your answer. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how code with ajax. So I did with gem [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon). Here's my code.

*new.html.erb*

```
else if (!isDuplicateEmail($('#user_email').val())) {
            $('#output-email').text('<%= t 'devise.registrations.output_email_duplicate' %>');
        }

function isDuplicateEmail(emailAddress) {
    if ($.inArray(emailAddress, gon.emails) == -1) {
        return true
    } return false
}
```

And in your controller you should put your variable with `gon`. This controller is sign_up with devise. So I put it in `new` method

*registrations_controller.rb*

```rb
def new
    gon.emails = User.pluck(:email)
    puts 'indexr'
    puts gon.emails
    super
end
```

For more explain about 'gon' read [this page](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript) please.

Comment: And first page will show 3 ways. But 1st and 2nd ways have critical security issue maybe. So I choose 3rd way.